# django storages breaks the admin staticfiles

Tags: django, django-storage, python-django-storages

I tried moving from local static files to S3 using django-storages. I followed the [documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) carefully but still there is no access to the static files.

In the local environment I have:

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

in the `settings.py` and everything works fine.

when I add all the S3 params as the documentation shows:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://django-main.s3.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'https://django-main.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/' # tried with this and also without this



DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name'
```

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` which seemed to work fine and uploaded the static files to the bucket.

but running the server and going to the admin page it looks like this:

[image]

which is because it doesn't have access to the static files. No error is thrown/shown

Any ideas?

EDIT:

So apperently I'm getting a forbbiden call:
[image]

but I changed my settings.py to:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

and made sure that access is available (put a breakpoint and downloaded a css file using boto3 from that bucket using these exact environment variables and still no solution

Comment: Did you check which url is being used to load the static files? Is your S3 correctly configured?

Comment: @hendrikschneider where do I see the url that is called? I believe that my S3 is configured correctly because `collectstatic` works and uploads all the files to the right bucket

Comment: Check the html of the page in your browser

Comment: @hendrikschneider please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Direction suggested by NotSoShabby is right. To further expand on this,

- Run `python manage.py collectstatic` (will take some time, as it will upload the static files to your bucket `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, patience in software dev. is the **key** and life in general ;))
- Check that the files have been added to `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME/admin/` prefix, if everthing is set up properly.
- Allow public access to the bucket (under the `Permission` tab) [**without this you will not able to added bucket policy**]
- Add appropriate policy to the bucket. `GetObject` permission should be enough for `admin/` prefix. For reference, I am adding my policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPublicAccessForStaticDjangoAdminFiles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME/admin/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the bucket read permissions were not public. Changing the permissions worked